# How to sort **boost::unordered_map** by value and return only keys in that order?

Tags: c++, boost

How to sort **boost::unordered_map** by value and return only keys in that order ?
I have map like **boost::unordered_map** and I need I need ony list of enums sorted by int values in asc/desc.

Comment: Do you need to sort it inplace? because that is more or less impossible (theoretically it might be possible to create a hash-function, which leads to a sorted `unordered:map`). Otherwise simply copy to a `map` (note the lack of `unordered_`) (or put pointers/iterators into the `unordered_map` into the `map` with an appropriate comparator) or into an `vector` and use `sort`.

Comment: If you needed to sort your map, you should have used a `map` instead of an `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `unordered_map` is, as the name implies, inherently not sorted or sortable in-place. You could insert the value pairs into a `set` that is sorted on the value and get the keys from there (using Boost.Range to make this stuff easier). I use a `std::set<T*>` to not pay the cost of copying the pair objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indirected.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

struct compare_second{
  template<class Pair>
  bool operator()(Pair* lhs, Pair* rhs) const{
    return lhs->second < rhs->second;
  }
};

template<class T>
struct make_pointer{
  typedef T* result_type;
  T* operator()(T& v) const{ return &v; }
};

int main(){
  using namespace boost::adaptors;
  std::unordered_map<int, int> m{{0,4},{1,3},{2,2},{3,1},{4,0}};
  typedef std::unordered_map<int,int>::value_type pair_type;
  auto p = m | transformed(make_pointer<pair_type>());
  std::set<pair_type*, compare_second> value_ordered(p.begin(), p.end());
  for(auto x : value_ordered | indirected | map_keys)
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3728661e999cf016707fd01c256767c0)

Comment: Note that a similar thing can be done with a `std::vector` and post-insertion sorting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Boost Multi-Index Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).
boost::multi_index_container can have ordered state and unordered state.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to copy the values into a vector and sort them by the mapped type:

```
std::vector<value_type> values(std::begin(map), std::end(map));
boost::sort(boost::make_range(values),
    [](const value_type &x, const value_type &y) { return x.second < y.second; });
std::vector<key_type> keys;
boost::push_back(keys, boost::make_range(values) | boost::map_keys));
```

Comment: I don't know the boost library enough, but I am not sure that the proposed solution will yield a list of the keys sorted by the *mapped value*. The approach to solve it will be similar, but I fear that it will take a bit more code. Again, not being familiar with the library I might not be understanding what the code does.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas oh, I didn't see that requirement.  Fixing.