# How to sort std::unordered_map by value in c++11 and get the most frequent elemts?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unordered-map

This question is similar to the:
[How to sort **boost::unordered_map** by value and return only keys in that order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263925/how-to-sort-boostunordered-map-by-value-and-return-only-keys-in-that-order)

But I want to know is there any new feature in c++11 that can solve the problem?

This program solved my problem:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
typedef multimap<int, unsigned int> saveMap;
typedef unordered_map<int, int> CounterMap;

CounterMap frequency(vector<int> numbers) {
    CounterMap counts;
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); ++j) {
        CounterMap::iterator i(counts.find(numbers[j]));
        if (i != counts.end()) {
            i->second++;
        } else {
            counts[numbers[j]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return counts;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector <int> vs{1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3};
    CounterMap v = frequency(vs);
    saveMap b;
    for (CounterMap::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {

        b.insert(make_pair(it->second, it->first));
    }
    for (saveMap::iterator it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first << "  " << it->second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question you linked, maps aren't (re)sortable, the question itself doesn't make any sense. If you want to sort the elements of a map by their value, you could always create another map that flips the keys and values.

Comment: @user657267: the crucial clarification needed for your statement being "create another [`std::map`]" not an `unordered_map`, which - as the name implies - aren't sortable at all.  Copying to a vector and sorting is another alternative.  Or, sometimes, a `boost::bimap` from the get go.

Comment: By "future", do you mean "feature"?  If so, no.  There is not.  The very use of `std::unordered_map` implies that the order is not important to you.

Comment: What are the sizes of the `key` and `value` types?  If they're particularly big, you may want to consider creating a sorted container of pointers or iterators to the `unordered_map` elements, as it'll use less memory and be faster, but you'll need a custom comparison operator that works on the referenced element values.